# register own taxonomy in standard posts

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I want to register my own taxonomy in standard, WP posts but it doesn't work. Look at my code

```
register_taxonomy(
    'special-category',
    array('post', 'books'),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => array(
        //...
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cpecial-category' )
    )
);
```

Tin my post type `books` it displays correctly but in standard wp post not. Is it possible to register own taxonomy in standard posts?

Comment: Yes. Try this: https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

Answer (score 0):

Try registering taxonomy in `init` hook.

Try out this code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_subjects_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
function create_subjects_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
 
// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
//first do the translations part for GUI
 
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Subjects', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Subject', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Subjects' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Subjects' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Subject' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Subject:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Subject' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Subject' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Subject' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Subject Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Subjects' ),
  );    
 
    // Now register the taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'special-category',
        array('post', 'books'),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
             //..
             ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cpecial-category' )
        )
    );
 
}
```

Comment: I forget said that I use `init` hook. I guess there's no other way?